# Avoiding "warning: Use of uninitialized value" when fetching an integer CGI parameter

Tags: integer, perl, null, cgi

I was using this code to fetch a CGI parameter:

```
$page = int(param('page'));
```

This sometimes results in:

```
warning: Use of uninitialized value in int
```

Is this a good solution to resolve this warning, or is better and more succinct code available?

```
if (defined param('page')) {
    $param_page = int(param('page'));
} else {
    $param_page = 1;
}
```

Comment: What is the `param` function?

Comment: I have `use CGI qw/:standard/` at the top of my script which imports the param() function. param() gets a value from the query string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard practice is to scope variables using `my`.

[Since Perl 5.10](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Defined-or-operator), the preferred way to write this is to use the [logical defined-or operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) to provide a default value when `undef` is encountered.

```
my $param_page = int(param('page') // 1);
```

Comment: By the way, if you think you should interpret an erroneous `"0"` parameter value as page 1, then you should use the `||` operator instead.